# What is the case convention of Nuxt.js file and folder naming?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-content, case-conversion

I'm creating files and folders in nuxt. Now I'm facing some confusion on the case convention of folders and file naming. Which case conventions are following the nuxt.js?  Like,

In the pages folder:

- folder: resetPassword / ResetPassword / reset-password / reset_password which is good?
- file: resetPassword.vue / ResetPassword.vue / reset-password.vue / reset_password which is good?

Answer (score 0):

For me, folder must be kebab case `reset-password`, except you create atomic folder like this. I prefer to use PascalCase.

```
components
├──ui
│  ├──Button
│  │  ├──Button.vue
│  │  ├──Button.stories.js
│  │  ├──Button.test
│  │  └──Button.scss
│  ├──Badge
│  │  ├──Badge.vue
│  │  ├──Badge.stories.js
│  │  ├──Badge.test
│  │  └──Badge.scss
│  └──...
└──...
```

And for component use PascalCase.

Source: https://zean.be/articles/vue-nuxtjs/.